# Is it undefined behavior when both the name of the member variable and parameter being passed in are the same?

Tags: c++

Lets say I have a class like the following:

```
class Base
{
  int a;

  public void Initialize(int a)
  {
    a = a;
  }
}
```

(Yes, this code is bad programming practice, but I just wrote it so it could be used as an example)

For the function Initialize, the name for both the member variables and the parameter being passed in are the same.

In this case, is this undefined behavior? Or does the compiler choose either the member variables (or parameters) in case there are any ambiguity.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's defined behavior... you're assigning the local variable `a` (the parameter) to itself.  If you want to assign it to the member, use `this->a = a;`

Answer (score 0):

When used in Initialize() like that, yes, you are simply assigning a to a (does nothing for int types). However, it works differently for constructors and initializer lists! If your code looked following:

```
Base(int a) : a(a) {}
```

It would actually initialize member a to argument a.