# Cout not printing out expected results

Tags: c++

When I compile the below code, for some reason, the student/instructors name, age, and GPA/Rating, are not returned via their respective printPerson functions.

With the **name** variable, nothing is printed to the console.
With the age, GPA/Rating, console prints out a negative 8 digit number, and a negative float.

What am I not seeing?

Person.h

```
#pragma once
#ifndef PERSON_H
#define PERSON_H
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>


using std::string;

// Base class
class Person {

protected:
    string name;
    int age;

public:
    void setName(string name);
    void setAge(int age);
    virtual void do_work(int number) {};
    virtual void printPerson() {};
};

#endif;
```

Person.cpp

```
#include "Person.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;


void Person::setName(string name) {
    name = name;
}

void Person::setAge(int age) {
    age = age;
}
```

Student.h

```
#pragma once
#ifndef STUDENT_H
#define STUDENT_H
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "Person.h"

using std::string;

class Student : public Person {

private:
    float gpa;


public:
    void setGPA(float gpa);
    float getGPA();
    void do_work(int number);
    void printPerson();
};

#endif;
```

Student.cpp

```
#include "Student.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>


using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;



 void Student::setGPA(float gpa) {
       gpa = gpa;
 }

 float Student::getGPA() {
       return gpa;
 }

 void Student::do_work(int number) {
       //cout << name << ".. " << number << "hours of homework.” << endl;
       cout << name;
 }

 void Student::printPerson() {
       cout << "Name : " << name << "Age :" << age << " GPA : " << getGPA() << endl;
}
```

Instructor.h

```
#pragma once
#ifndef INSTRUCTOR_H
#define INSTRUCTOR_H
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "Person.h"

class Instructor : public Person {

private:
    float rating;

public:
    void setRating(float rating);
    float getRating();
    void do_work(int number);
    void printPerson();
};

#endif;
```

Instructor.cpp

```
#include "Instructor.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>


using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

void Instructor::setRating(float rating) {
    rating = rating;
}

float Instructor::getRating() {
    return rating;
}

void Instructor::do_work(int number) {
    cout << name << "graded papers for" << number << "hours." << endl;
}

void Instructor::printPerson() {
    cout << " Name : " << name << " Age : " << age << " Rating : " << getRating() << endl;
}
```

University.h

```
#pragma once
#ifndef UNIVERSITY_H
#define UNIVERSITY_H
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "Person.h"
#include "Building.h"
#include "Student.h"


using std::cout;
using std::string;
using std::vector;

class University {

public:
    string name;
    vector<Person*> persons;
    vector<Building> buildings;

public:
    void printAllBuildings();
    void printAllPersonsRecord();
};

#endif;
```

University.cpp

```
#include "University.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>


using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

void University::printAllBuildings() {
    cout << " Building Details : " << endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < buildings.size(); j++) {
       buildings[j].printBuilding();
    }
}

void University::printAllPersonsRecord() {
    cout << " Persons Details : " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < persons.size(); i++) {
       persons[i]->printPerson();
    }
}
```

Building.h

```
#pragma once
#ifndef BUILDING_H
#define BUILDING_H
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "Person.h"

class Building {
public:
    string name;
    int size;
    string address;

public:
    void printBuilding();
};

#endif;
```

Building.cpp

```
#include "Building.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>


using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

void Building::printBuilding() {
    cout << " Name : " << name << " Address : " << address << endl;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "University.h"
#include "Person.h"
#include "Student.h"
#include "Instructor.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>


using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

int main() {

    Student student;
    Instructor instructor;

    student.setName("deepak");
    student.setAge(12);
    student.setGPA(12.0);

    instructor.setName("rajdev");
    instructor.setAge(23);
    instructor.setRating(5.0);

    Building building;

    building.name = "block1";
    building.size = 2000;
    building.address = "noida sector-2";

    Building building2;

    building2.name = "block2";
    building2.size = 4000;
    building2.address = "noida sector-2";

    University university;

    university.name = "Oregon State University";
    university.persons.emplace_back(&student);
    university.persons.emplace_back(&instructor);
    university.buildings.push_back(building);
    university.buildings.push_back(building2);

    university.printAllBuildings();

    university.printAllPersonsRecord();

    int choice;
    bool isValidMainChoice = false;
    while (!isValidMainChoice) {
       cout << "Kindly choose one of the option from follwoing list of operations or Menu" << endl;
       cout << "1 : Prints names of all the buildings" << endl;
       cout << "2 : Prints names of everybody at the university" << endl;
       cout << "3 : Choose a person to do work" << endl;
       cout << "4 : Exit the program" << endl;
       cin >> choice;
       cout << "The value you entered is " << choice << endl;
       if (choice == 1) {
          university.printAllBuildings();
       }
       else if (choice == 2) {
          university.printAllPersonsRecord();
       }
       else if (choice == 3) {
          int personChoice;
          bool isInputValid = false;
          while (!isInputValid) {
             cout << "Kindly choose the one of the following option to provide person's details." << endl;
             cout << "5 : Student" << endl;
             cout << "6 : Instructor" << endl;
             cin >> personChoice;
             if (personChoice == 5) {
                isInputValid = true;
                string studentName;
                bool isValidName = false;
                while (!isValidName) {
                    cout << " Kindly enter Name of the student :" << endl;
                    cin >> studentName;
                    if (studentName.length() == 0) {
                       cout << " Name must not be blank. Kindly re-enter the student's name." << endl;
                    }
                    else {
                       isValidName = true;
                    }
                }
                int age1 = 0;
                bool isValidAge1 = false;
                while (!isValidAge1) {
                    cout << " Kindly enter age of the student :" << endl;
                    cin >> age1;
                    if (age1 < 0 || age1 > 100) {
                       cout << " Age must be geter than 0 or lessa then 100. Kindly re-enter the student's age." << endl;
                    }
                    else {
                       isValidAge1 = true;
                    }
                }
                float gpa;
                bool isValidGPA = false;
                while (!isValidGPA) {
                    cout << " Kindly enter GPA of the student :" << endl;
                    cin >> gpa;
                    if (gpa < 0.0 || gpa > 4.0) {
                       cout << " GPA must be geter than 0.0 or less then 4.0. Kindly re-enter the Student GPA." << endl;
                       isValidGPA = false;
                    }
                    else {
                       isValidGPA = true;
                    }
                }
                Student student;
                student.setName(studentName);
                student.setAge(age1);
                student.setGPA(gpa);
                university.persons.emplace_back(&student);
                university.printAllPersonsRecord();
             }
             else if (personChoice == 6) {
                isInputValid = true;
                string instructorName;
                bool isValidName = false;
                while (!isValidName) {
                    cout << " Kindly enter Name of the instructor :" << endl;
                    cin >> instructorName;
                    if (instructorName.length() == 0) {
                       cout << " Name must not be blank. Kindly re-enter the instructor's name." << endl;
                    }
                    else {
                       isValidName = true;
                    }
                }

                float rating;
                bool isValidRating = false;
                while (!isValidRating) {
                    cout << " Kindly enter rating of the instructor :" << endl;
                    cin >> rating;
                    if (rating < 0.0 || rating > 5.5) {
                       cout << " rating must be geter than 0.0 or less then 5.5. Kindly re-enter the instructor rating." << endl;
                       isValidRating = false;
                    }
                    else {
                       isValidRating = true;
                    }
                }
                int age2 = 0;
                bool isValidAge2 = false;
                while (!isValidAge2) {
                    cout << " Kindly enter age of the instructor :" << endl;
                    cin >> age2;
                    if (age2 < 0 || age2 > 100) {
                       cout << " Age must be geter than 0 or lessa then 100. Kindly re-enter the instructor's age." << endl;
                    }
                    else {
                       isValidAge2 = true;
                    }
                }
                Instructor instructor;
                instructor.setName(instructorName);
                instructor.setAge(age2);
                instructor.setRating(rating);
                university.persons.emplace_back(&instructor);
             }
             else {
                cout << "The value you entered is incorrct.Please r-enter the values." << endl;
             }
          }
       }
       else if (choice == 4) {
          isValidMainChoice = true;
          cout << " You are exits from system. Thanks You !!" << endl;
       }
    }
    return 0;
};
```

Comment: That's too much code to look at to figure out where the problem(s) is. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it undefined behavior when both the name of the member variable and parameter being passed in are the same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32236584/is-it-undefined-behavior-when-both-the-name-of-the-member-variable-and-parameter)

Comment: The parameters to your `set` methods have the same name as the member variable being set.  This will set the parameter value to the parameter value, and not set the member variable.  Call the parameters something else.

Answer (score 1):

Please modify all your code for ***setter***

```
void Person::setName(string name) {
    //before-edit: name = name;
    this->name = name; //OR Person::name = name;
}
```

As the local string ***name*** parameter and your class variable are the same, you expect the parameter are passed correctly, but it doesn't.